# Running Hue Server on a MULTI-NODE CLUSTER

Tags: hadoop, oozie, hue

I am running a fully functional installation of (multi-node) hadoop on my cluster.

I have been trying to set up Hue and Oozie and have managed to run it to some extent, but I get a misconfiguration error when I try to open Hue saying:

```
Failed to contact JobTracker plugin at None:9290
```

I have tried configuring my `pseudo-distributed.ini` file as well as `oozie-site.xml` file, but the error continues to occur.

Comment: Can you add the contents of your `pseudo-distributed.ini` and `oozie-site.xml` files to your question?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: You need to specify the hostname of the JobTracker in [[jobtracker_host]] in the hue.ini (and install the Job Tracker plugin if on MR1). Check http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/cdh_ig_cdh_hue_configure.html?scroll=topic_15_4#topic_15_4_2_unique_1

Comment: Is hue.ini same as pseudo-distributed.ini? I have given the details about the jobtracker and the port it runs in the pseudo-distributed.ini file.